# Is there a 128 or 256 bit double class in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, math, class, double

I have an application that I want to be able to use large numbers and very precise numbers. For this, I needed a precision interpretation and IntX only works for integers.

Is there a class in .net framework or even third party(preferably free) that would do this?

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: ^ Decimal doesn't have anywhere near the dynamic range of double or float as no exponent. See quad precision float in c# answer below!

Comment: @Dr.ABT: It does have an exponent... but a much smaller one than double, smaller even than float, even considering the different base.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe the [Decimal type](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) would work for you?

Comment: Thanks Guys, I was wondering about performance but with the amount of precision I get, this shouldn't be a problem. Can decimal handle large numbers though?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230105/net-decimal-what-in-sql, Decimal can handle up to 29 digits to the left of the decimal point (and 28 to the right). Is that large enough?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker link is broken

Comment: @sra: Thanks for the heads-up. I've updated the link to an article by Jon Skeet. That one should be more stable :)

Comment: There's another drawback to using Decimal, and that's dynamic range. Decimal.MaxValue is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335, or 7.9E28. It can't be used as a substitute for double calculations with higher precision, since Double has a dynamic range of +/- 1E308

Comment: Decimal also is only 102 bits... with  26 bits of padding.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the freely available, arbitrary precision, [BigDecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa286442%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) from `java.math`, which is part of the [J# redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f72c74b3-ed0e-4af8-ae63-2f0e42501be1) from Microsoft and is a managed .NET library.

Place a reference to vjslib in your project and you can something like this:

```
using java.math;

public void main() 
{
    BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal("1234567890123456789011223344556677889900.0000009876543210000987654321");
    big.add(new BigDecimal(1.0));
    Debug.Print(big);
}
```

Will print the following to the debug console:

> 1234567890123456789011223344556677889901.0000009876543210000987654321

Note that, as already mentioned, .NET 2010 contains a [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.aspx) class which, as a matter of fact, was already available in earlier versions, but only as internal class (i.e., you'd need some reflection to get it to work).

Answer (score 5):

The F# library has some really big number types as well if you're okay with using that...

Comment: Hi Justin, interested to hear more - can we do long-double (80bits or 128bits) in f#? All the decimal types in C# have high bits but no exponent

Answer (score 5):

I've been searching for a solution for this for a long time, and today came across this library:

[Quadruple Precision Double in C#](http://quadruple.codeplex.com)

> Signed 128-bit floating point data type library, with 64 effective bits of precision (vs. 53 for Doubles) and a 64 bit exponent (vs. 11 for Doubles). Quads have greater precision and far greater range than Doubles and are especially useful when dealing with very large or very small values, such as those in probabilistic models. As of version 2.0, all Quad arithmetic is checked (underflowing to 0, overflowing to +/- infinity), has special PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity, and NaN values, and follows the same rules as .Net Double arithmetic and comparison operators (e.g. 1/0 == PositiveInfinity, 0 * PositiveInfinity == NaN, NaN != NaN), making it a convenient drop-in replacement for Doubles in existing code.

Answer (score 3):

If Decimal doesn't work for you, try implementing (or grabbing code from somewhere) `Rational` arithmetic using large integers.  That will provide the precision you need.

Comment: Got a link for something I could port?

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson There is https://github.com/AdamWhiteHat/BigRational/

Answer (score 3):

Shameless plug: [QPFloat](https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat) emulates the IEEE standard to full precision.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm about 12 years late to the party.

I just thought you'd like to use my arbitrary precision floating point class called BigDecimal (I should have named it BigFloat, but its kinda late for that now).

Well, more correctly it will provide precision up to the number of digits you specify (by setting the static BigDecimal.Precision member), that way it doesn't use up all your ram trying to represent irrational numbers.

I put a lot of effort into ensuring its correctness and working out all the bugs. It comes with a test project that tests every method in multiple ways, and each bug I fixed started by adding a test case.

And unlike QPFloat and the J# redistributable's BigDecimal, the code is not an incomprehensible mess and follows C# coding style and naming conventions (to be fair, part of unreadability of J#'s version comes from the fact that you have to decompile the assembly first, so it'll be missing the names of all the private members).

### Link drop:

[BigDecimal on GitHub](https://github.com/AdamWhiteHat/BigDecimal)

[ExtendedNumerics.BigDecimal on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedNumerics.BigDecimal)

Answer (score 2):

Use `decimal` for this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal is a 128-bit (16 byte) value type that is used for highly precise calculations. It is a floating point type that is represented internally as base 10 instead of base 2 (i.e. binary). If you need to be highly precise, you should use Decimal - but the drawback is that Decimal is about 20 times slower than using floats.

Comment: Decimal contains 26 bits of padding zeros, so it's really only 102 bits.

Answer (score 1):

`Decimal` is 128 bits if that would work.