# What's a good way to store extremely large numbers? (Eg. 572e6561) in C#

Tags: c#, math, numbers

My first thought was to implement a class which stores the coefficient as a double, and the 10^X as an int/short.

I want to use engineering notation over scientific notation because it's simpler for end-users.

If there are projects for doing this, I can't seem to find them.

I know `System.Numerics.BigInteger` exists, but it's pretty slow. I really want high speed for performing many calculations on mobile devices.
I just want to store numbers as engineering notation.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are going to implement your own class, it makes more sense to use int for mantessa as well as the exponent. or use a library if possible

Comment: Yeah I realized int would probably be best for both, but I'm not sure how exactly to implement it in a way that isn't slow. Know of any good libraries for this?

Comment: integer ops arent slow, its just a matter of renormalizing your mantesssa - which any extended presicion library will do. this may give a few suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967723/is-there-a-128-or-256-bit-double-class-in-net

Comment: If you won't be using them for a long time, they can be stored in the freezer. If you need them right away, however, store them in a paper bag on top of the refrigerator.

Comment: What are your expected maximum ranges?

Comment: Around 1x10^10,000 (1e10,000.) An int will suffice for the mantissa precision. I was just hoping someone had already implemented it somewhere.

Comment: My advice is to use an existing library for arbitrary precision floats, since there are lots of subtleties which someone else has figured out already. It appears that there are C# bindings for [GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library) and [MPIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPIR_%28mathematics_software%29). There are probably others.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a lot of precision, just large magnitudes, then I'd say use two values to represent mantissa and exponent. Using integers for both would be closer to how floating point numbers are handled internally. But using floating point at least for the mantissa would probably make it easier to implement many of the operations, at the cost of a few bits of mantissa precision.

C has functions like [frexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/frexp) and [ldexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/ldexp) to separately deal with mantissa and exponent of a floating point number. I don't know any C# or .NET, but perhaps similar functions are available there as well.

If you use double for the exponent as well, you'd theoretically *really* big numbers. But if that exponent isn't exact, due to rounding, then you don't know the exponent at all, which makes the mantissa worthless. So if you need numbers big enough to consider such things, you either need to use some big integer for the exponent, or can drop the mantissa completely and just express those big numbers as powers of two with an approximate exponent.