# Massive numbers in C# without using BigInteger

Tags: c#

I'm porting a JavaScript game into C#, an interesting feature of this game is that there are dozens of resources which grow from fractions per second to over e^thousands per second.

I need to be able to do standard math operations / string formats on these numbers many times a second ... mostly addition as resources accumulate and division to show how many of x I can buy with y or how long it'll take to complete a goal given a per second progress.

In C# I've tried using various 3rd party large number solutions (Rational / BigDecimal / BigFloat) all of which use System.Numerics.BigInteger under the hood ... and I've tried just using BigIntegers. All of these are functional but suffer from unacceptable performance.

My use-case doesn't need arbitrarily large (expected practical range is +/- e5000) or precise (6 decimal places is comfortably enough) numbers but I *do* need simple math operations to be significantly faster than BigInteger will provide. What are potential solutions to this problem?

Edit 1 - the JS game uses BigDecimal.js ... which also has performance issues later game when the numbers get really large.

Edit 2 - For anyone down-voting I'd really appreciate an explanation why.

Edit 3 - rephrased as a single question / to be more on topic.

Comment: Have you tried `[System.Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx)'?

Comment: @Jonathan Tyson It's good to like 28 decimal places....

Comment: [Here's something](http://quadruple.codeplex.com/)
128 bit floating point library

Comment: Is there a reason you can relate to us why you require numbers 25 times larger than the sum of all the atoms in the universe?

Comment: @harold the JS code uses BigDecimal.js

Comment: @hoodaticus that's just what this game happens to be about - growing completely ridiculous numbers of things.

Comment: OOOH Aurigan that sounds like fun!  You are caught between two extremes.  Integers can represent the numbers with no loss of precision but yours will need to be over 2KB.  The largest integer register on any commodity processor is 128 bytes and I'm not sure you can do math on the whole register as a single number.  So you're talking about multi-word integer mathematics on probably QWords which means you don't have enough registers in the CPU (> 128) to hold everything needed to add 1 to that number.  So floating point - with its loss of precision - is your only performant option.

Comment: _"...suffer from unacceptable performance..."_ - hmm, well JavaScript is hardly a **bastion of performance**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin

Comment: @JonathanTyson Decimal only has +/- e28 range, I need +/-e5000. The quadruple library on the other hand *does* look promising, thanks!

Comment: @hoodaticus this may be absurdly pedantic given the context, but... *observable* universe, surely...

Comment: I think javascript's BigDecimal is based on Java's BigDecimal. There is a way to use Java's BigDecimal from c#. See one of the answers to this question, which talks about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967723/is-there-a-128-or-256-bit-double-class-in-net

Comment: Note - my math was slightly off.  Your desired number range is more than 25 *orders of magnitude* larger than the sum of the atoms in the *observable* universe, not 25 times.

Comment: @hoodaticus :) still not close. Atoms in observable universe: ~e80, numbers I need: e5000 ... so 4920 orders of magnitude larger.

Comment: @JonathanTyson Just to let you know it looks like that quad struct will work out perfectly - 100's of times more performant than using the other solutions I mentioned, has more precision than I need by a long way and a +/- e2776511644261678592 range which is ... sufficient ;) Please add it as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Since you don't need a lot of precision what's the problem with using the existing floating point numbers??

Comment: @LorenPechtel a double will only store up to e308, I need to store / perform calculations on numbers much, much larger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://quadruple.codeplex.com/) is a library for quadruple floats (128 bits) with 64 bits of precision and a 64-bit exponent. I haven't used it, but it seems to be reasonably performant considering what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its a shame that codeplex closed. Id recommend https://github.com/AdamWhiteHat/BigDecimal/ https://github.com/AdamWhiteHat/BigRational/ for arbitrary precision or https://github.com/coder0xff/QPFloat/ if you had your heart set on quadruple precision floating points.